# VLC is cropping my video for projector display

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, external-display, fullscreen, projector

**Context: What works:**
I'm trying to set up my VLC so that it displays through a projector. I set up my screen with two monitors, and set up VLC to have DirectX drawing to draw to the other screen. That works perfectly fine (I just followed the steps [here](http://www.kec.org.au/blog/2012/07/vlc-setup-for-output-to-projector-using-extended-desktop/)). It displays on the projector.
**What doesn't work:**
The problem is that the second monitor display window, when in fullscreen, is too large for the second display; the video playing is a 16:9 and the projector's window is a 4:3 ratio, so when I drag a video in to play it, it gets cut off.
**What I've tried:**
Now, I am able to press the fullscreen button twice to shrink and re-enlarge it to make it fit with a black margin on the top and bottom. These margins are exactly what I want - BUT: I need the window to fit the screen automatically when I open a file, and each time I open a new file, it resets.
Is there a way to manually set the margins, or to make it so it automatically fits, or even mess with my projector output settings (win7)?
Thanks to anyone who can help me!

Answer (score 0):

Right click --> video --> always fit window

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).